# Will Google index "www.example.com/#!hash"?

Tags: ajax, web-crawler, googlebot

I read [here](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=174992) that Google will index AJAX content for a URL that looks like this "www.example.com/page.html#!hash".
I'm wondering if anybody knows if "www.example.com/#!hash" would also work, as it is shorter and more user friendly.

Comment: Please refer to [the FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) for questions that are on-topic for SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it will. As long as you rewrite it correctly using "_escaped_fragment_".
To make sure it is working properly, after setting everything up according to their manual, you can use google webmaster tools to "see what crawling bot sees" when accessing URLs like that

Comment: If I get Google correctly, the URL they are crawling instead would then be "www.example.com/?_escaped_fragment_=hash". Is that a valid URL (since there is no filename)?